# Python does not allow multiple return() statements in ternary; possible alternative that is also aesthetically pleasing?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am developing a text based RPG (graphics will be implemented later) and I am writing a method to determine whether a room a player is trying to go to exists or not. In this method I have multiple logic statements that determine what room the player is trying to get to based on the direction they enter and whether that "room" == 0 (my place holder for an empty space in the world/dungeon array). 
Although I can write a conventional logic statement for this:

```
if condition:
    if otherCondition:
        return(True)
    else:
        return(False)
```

a ternary is much more aestheticaly pleasing:

```
if condition:
    return(True) if otherCondition else return(False)
```

But of course, that does not work. I am looking for something that functions as the conventional logic statement but is also "pleasing to the eye", like a ternary. In my code the logic statement is repeated four times, and the conventional logic statement would be displeasing to read.

I am using **Python 3.5.1** on **Windows 7**.

Comment: @timgeb: Not quite right. The original code keeps going if `condition` is false.

Comment: Note: It's just `return`, not `return()`

Comment: Aesthetics is matter of taste, but to me, the ternary variant seems much more difficult to understand.

Comment: `return` is a statement. Statements can contain expressions (where the grammar allows for expressions). A conditional expression (`... if ... else  ...)` is an expression. Expressions can't ever contain statements, so a conditional expression can't contain `return`.

Comment: `return <expression>` returns the result of the expression. `... if ... else ...` produces the result of one of two nested expressions, based on a test. Just have the expression produce the right value, so `return True if otherCondition else False`, or much simpler `return bool(otherCondition)` or `return otherCondition` if the `otherCondition` itself produces a boolean already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue with your *statement* isn't the ternary part, it's the repeated return. Instead use:

```
if condition:
    return True if otherCondition else False
```

Here, the result of the *expression* `True if otherCondition else False` is returned.

This could be written more concisely as:

```
if condition:
    return bool(otherCondition)
```

Comment: Your first code section is precisely what I'm looking for, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Use just a single `return` with ternary statement:

```
return 'something' if someCondition else 'something else'
```

For you case is enough just :

```
if condition:
   return otherCondition
   # or if "otherCondition is not bool you can use: return bool(condition)
```

Comment: If `condition` is false, we're not supposed to return at all. `return condition or otherCondition` is wrong.

Comment: `return bool(otherCondition)` if it is not yet a boolean.

Comment: @AlexanderTrakhimenok: Still wrong. `return condition and otherCondition` still returns when `condition` is false, which it's not supposed to do.

Comment: @user2357112 we can not know for sure if it's wrong or not based on provided code. if it's end of function it would return None automatically and if checked as boolean result it would be equivalent to False. If there is code to run after the conditions check it's wrong, but it's offtopics as question was about ternanry operation & return

Answer (score 1):

```
z = x if success else y
# this tallies z = success ? x : y, where success is a bool. Either True or False
```

Here the expression on the right returns `x` or `y` depending on if `success` evaluates to `True` or `False` respectively. As this is an expression it can be used with a return statement

```
return x if success else y
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how it answers the question would significantly improve its long-term value. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation.

Comment: @JasonMc92 Edited the answer.

Comment: Awesome, thanks. I'd upvote, but I used all my votes already this morning. I'll try and remember to come by later.

Comment: @JasonMc92 Thanks. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
if condition:
    return othercondition
```

Comment: @AlexanderTrakhimenok No, it can't. Also, per Martijn's comment, it would probably be best to explicitly cast `othercondition` to a boolean.

Comment: @AlexanderTrakhimenok: If you mean with `and` or something, no it can't. I've been trying to tell you that it can't. If you mean by putting `return othercondition` on the same line as the `if` statement instead of on the line after, that's doable, but generally discouraged.

Comment: @user2357112, I guess you are right but it depend on how we read the question. For me it's more about using ternary & return together rather then actual logic.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you should illustrate with an example, because it can be simplified to return the result of the other condition.

```
if condition:
    return otherCondition
```

Answer (score 0):

What ever happened to just:

```
if condition:
    # tis very simple; if room is equal to 0, the operation is true, thus `True` will be returned
    # otherwise `False`.. no mystery 
    return room == 0
```